# iPhone app behave differently on device connected to instrument vs without instrument vs simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

i got an app that provide swap gesture to swap image location
between 2 image. Let say my template for 5 image in different
location and I wanna swap and change location 1 with location 5.
The app perform well on simulator and device that connected to instrument (leak) but if i compile the code just and run directly to device without instrument (leak) sometime the image at location 1
will go missing (show black screen).

Suppose the app running on device that connected to instrument and without instrument should perform the same right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it may not. The ultimate test is on a real device without instruments. Instruments sometime change the way memory is managed to look for leaks or to measure memory used or to track down zombies.

You should use instruments only for that purpose and not as a final test suite.

It seems you have a memory issue here. Check your allocs/deallocs